# Backing up 2 computers

Tags: backup

I have 2 laptops that i would like to have the same videos, pictures, and documents on. both run Ubuntu, both have a media partition with mostly the same videos and stuff on them. Ubuntu one has only 5gb so I can't use that. There is like 50gb+ of stuff on the media partitions. I have an external drive 500gb I'd like to use that. 
should I clown the drives with the videos? then install the same backup services on them? then have my 500gb external drive back up both with the same info?
does any of this make any sense? 
thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

If you work with the same documents on both computers, I would (actually I did) the following:

Use the external drive (sooner or later you will want to work with a NAS) as "working" directory, automount it to both computers, and use one of the computers as a backup directory for the shared directory.

I believe synchronizing is risky, because if you change files on one of the computers without being in the network, it will cause version conflicts if you accidentally edit the same documents later on the other one.